# How can I copy and paste a range of Word document as a picture in a PowerPoint slide using C#?

Tags: c#

I have a word doc:
[image]

When i coppy all range in Word doc and paste as picture in a PPT Slide

[image]

The text is faulty.

It should be
[image]

But the result is:

[image]

It will fail when I use accented letters.

How can i fix it?

My Code:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(linkfileWord);
        Range rng = wordDoc.Range();
        rng.Copy();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides slides;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Slide slide;
        // Create the Presentation File
        Presentation pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoTrue);
        CustomLayout customLayout = pptPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[3];
        // Create new Slide
        slides = pptPresentation.Slides;
        slide = slides.AddSlide(1, customLayout);

        slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(PpPasteDataType.ppPasteMetafilePicture);

        pptPresentation.SaveAs(pathfolder_ppt, PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsDefault, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

Comment: `My text is error. How can i fix it?` Can you be more explicit about the issue you are facing?

Comment: @mjwills see last edit. Please help me. It will fail when I use accented letters.